# Name of the font used in Linux Console (TTY)

Tags: console, tty, fonts

What is the name of the font that is used in Linux Console TTY 1-6?

[image]

Comment: It's whatever has been configured on your system, or whatever the video card provides. You're apparently using Ubuntu, I don't know if it has a consistent default. Try [identifont](http://www.identifont.com/).

Comment: Maybe by the image it looks like I'm using Ubuntu, but this is not the screenshot of my system, Although the font is same here. I'm using Fedora 21. And I was wanting to know how to find out the name of the font (default or not) which is currently being used by the virtual console.
A sort of command.

Comment: Maybe some of these could help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97469/what-is-the-default-debian-ubuntu-console-tty-font-called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The font in the image you supplied is the VGA font (I believe people refer to it as the VGA 437 font, but it's ambiguous; take a look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).) This rendering is not something specific to Linux – it's your graphics card's rendition. Every graphics card I've used has used this particular rendering by default. I found a TTF clone of it [here](http://www.dafont.com/perfect-dos-vga-437.font).

The Linux TTY has other fonts and sizes too. If you want to customize it, try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Comment: Although the command you mentioned doesn't work for Fedora (as it is not Debian-based), but the font looks pretty similar. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the shape of the letter M, it's a generic VGA 8x16 font.  (If the middle of the M was thicker, it'd be the more widely used but less efficient to emulate VGA 9x16 font.)

The [Oldschool PC Font Resource](https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/) has very well made modern font files that are pixel-perfect replicas of these older character glyphs.  Click on "The Fonts" at the top of the page to see samples, and the download link is at the top of the screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

In opensuse this (or very similar) font is called Misc Console and can be installed from the misc-console-font package.