# Terminal emulator that looks like TTY?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there a graphical terminal emulator that looks like the tty screen just
before the login?

I pretty much like the way the tty looks: the font, the high-contrast colors,
and the small padding between text and the screen itself.

For example, there is little to no padding between the command bar in Vim on
tty. However, on alacritty/st/and other terminal emulators there is large,
inconvenient gaps between the command bar and the bottom of the terminal, as
well as large padding on top and on both sides. The same thing for other TUI
programs, such as neomutt and newsboat.

If there were a terminal emulator that looks near exactly like tty that would
be awesome. Does anyone know of such program? If not, is it possible to eliminate
weird padding of those popular terminal emulators I just mentioned?

Comment: [Name of the font used in Linux Console (TTY)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202796). XTerm has `internalBorder` (which you can set to zero) and a resource whose name I forget (read the manual if interested) to tweak line separation distance. "On alacritty/st/and other terminal emulators there is large, inconvenient gaps between the command bar and the bottom of the terminal" the character cell size obviously determines this. If the screen size is a multiple of it, then you get no gap.

Comment: can I set `internalBorder` to 0 in terminals other than Xterm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xfce4-terminal` can run in full screen mode and and if you have a single tab open, pretty much everything will be dedicated to your shell.

As for fonts, I'm a huge fan of Terminus. I've been using various OSes for three decades and I haven't seen a better font for a terminal and coding.

[image: xfce4-terminal with terminus - open at native resolution]

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Does this have Vim keybindings? Like Alacritty, in which you can go to into visual mode and select text from previous commands. It's quite handy